# How to use context module instead of panel module?

Tags: 7, users, configuration

I am unable to set user permission on particular section of panel. For example I have used 3 column  panel layout for particular page and want to set view permission to only one column out of three to particular set of people. But I didn't found any settings for the same in panels. So I tried with context module but I do not have much information on context module and how it works for page layout and permission.
Can anyone help me in that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a visibility rule for user role to the panes you add in your Panels columns. Seems like just what you need.

Comment: Thanks Arjan. I am able to add visibility settings for user role to panel pages. But I didn't found any settings for particular column or section of layout. It would be helpful if you can mention from where I can set role based permission for particular column of layout.

Comment: I don't believe you can configure this per region, but you can set it for each piece of content (pane) that you add to the region (block, views block, node, etc.).